# Can you pass serialized ajax data, along with other variables at once?

Tags: jquery, ajax

So i have input fields, which i add the DOM with jquery.All i want to do is to pass their data, once they have one and the data from the html option element, all as $_POST elements.

```js
$('#intake_input').on('click',function(e){
   
       var days =$('.intake-pick').find(":selected").val();
       
      $.ajax({
          dataType: "json",
          type:     "post",
          data: {$('form').serialize(), "broi_dni": days},
          cache:    false,
          url:      '/ajax/intake/intake_ajax.php',
          success:  function(result){
              if(result === true)
              $(this).submit();
          }
          
      })
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form method = "POST">
    <section class = "intake-body">
     <select class = "intake-pick">
     
      <option value = "2">Две полета</option>
      <option value = "3">Три полета</option>
      <option value = "4">Четири полета</option>
      <option value = "5">Пет полета</option>
      <option value = "6">Шест полета</option>
      <option value = "7">Седем полета</option>
      <option value = "8">Осем полета</option>
      <option value = "9">Девет полета</option>
      <option value = "10">Десет полета</option>
      <option value = "11">Единадесет полета</option>
      <option value = "12">Дванадесет полета</option>
            <option value = "13">Тринадесет полета</option>
      <option value = "14">Четиринадесет полета</option>
      
     </select>
    </section>
</form>
```

As you can see i want to pass `$('.form').serialize()` and `days` variable as $_POST["broi_dni"] in php but it doesn't want to pass both of them, unless i add it as a string like that:

`data: posts.serialize() + "broi_dni" + days,`

Which is returning:

[image]

It returns the $_POST['broi_dni'] which i need as a string in my last array element...

Is there a way to pass both serialize data and other variables as a $_POST in php ?

Thanks for your time! Sorry for my stupidity.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add `name` attribute to your `select` and its value will be included in `$('form').serialize()`:

```
<select class = "intake-pick" name="broi_dni">
  ...


data: $('form').serialize(),
```